# First query using elasticsearch_dsl is slow, but the second is fast

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Below I have written a simple function that is querying an index. I intentionally put the connection inside of `stack_over_flow_example`. The first query takes almost 1 second, and the second takes 0.1 second. Always on the first call I have this delay. When I use Kibana to do this query, I take 0.1 second always, it doesn't matter if it's the first or the last. Is this normal in this elastic wrapper???

```
import time

from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import create_connection
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search


def stack_over_flow_example(text):
    start = time.time()
    connection = create_connection(**my_own_configuration)
    search = Search(using = connection, index = 'MyIndexName').query("match", my_field = text)
    search.execute()
    print(time.time()- start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stack_over_flow_example("SomeTextA")
    stack_over_flow_example("SomeTextB")
```

Comment: post your index mapping

Comment: Kibana always holds connections to elastisearch. Your application maybe not? Try to issue the query via curl, the response times should be similar. If so, think about tcp/ip and http handshake and connection keepalive in your application

Comment: If you intend to interact with elastic multiple time in a short span, i'd recommend moving create_connection call to main and then when you want to use it you can call get_connection() (instead of passing the obj around, just modify your import). Likely, create_connection checks for an existing one first which is why the first call would take longer.